# How to start a process from Java with arguments which contain double-quotes

Tags: java, command-line, process, command-line-arguments

I need to start a second Java process from my Java program, and one of the arguments to the forked process need to contain literal double-quote characters (`"`). How do I do that in a portable way, i.e. so that it at least works on Linux and Windows?

---

I tried to use a `ProcessBuilder` (which was introduced to overcome problems of the `Runtime` class, right?) with an array of strings as command line, but still there was a problem with the parameter containing the quote:

```
List<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();
commandLine.add(new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java").getAbsolutePath());
commandLine.addAll(Arrays.asList("-jar", "plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar", "-application", "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director", "-repository", "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno"));
commandLine.add("-list");
commandLine.add("Q:select(x | x.id == \"org.eclipse.sdk.ide\")");

new ProcessBuilder().command(commandLine).directory(eclipseInstallationDir).start().waitFor();
```

The code above doesn't work (on Windows) because the `ProcessBuilder` (or something else) eats up the double quotes in the last argument:

Instead of `Q:select(x | x.id == "org.eclipse.sdk.ide")`, the process receives the argument `Q:select(x | x.id == org.eclipse.sdk.ide)` and then fails.

---

I figured out that I can make it work on Windows by adding a `\"` in the argument where I need a `"` i.e.

```
commandLine.add("Q:select(x | x.id == \"org.eclipse.sdk.ide\")".replace("\"", "\\\""));
```

but this breaks the invocation on Linux (as morgano confirmed). So I'm forced to detect the OS again. Is there really no simple, portable way to start a process in Java where the arguments are exactly the content of a string array?

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: Which one? The one with or without replace? And on which OS?

Comment: The first one (the one with the string `"Q:select(x | x.id == \"org.eclipse.sdk.ide\")"`)

Comment: And what happens if you append the `.replace("\"", "\\\"")` in Java? Does the forked process in Linux then see a parameter with a literal backslash?

Comment: Replacing as you say, Linux "sees" this parameter: `Q:select(x | x.id == \"org.eclipse.sdk.ide\")`

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a command argument string is split around spaces to form an array of arguments. However, if you want a single argument to contain a space, you can wrap the argument in quotes. Later, each *pair* of quotes will be removed from the string. It's not java that is removing these quotes--it's the operating system itself which does this.

ProcessBuilder is wrapping each of the arguments you supply in quotes so that if any of the arguments contains a space, it will not be split into multiple arguments further down the road by the operating system (you can hack this by supplying `1234\" \"5678`; this will be end up being two arguments: `1234`, and `5678`). Then ProcessBuilder concatenates all the arguments together into one command, which it passes to the operating system. Later, the operating system splits the command string by whitespace and quotes (as described above), and then removes all pairs of quotes from each string argument before it begins the new process. To escape a quote (i.e. treat it as a regular character that is not handled differently by the OS parser), use a backslash character before it. This is the command line escape character for both Linux and Windows. This will look like: `\\\"`.

Comment: Why is there a "further down the road"? I have a perfectly list of arguments that wouldn't need any magic. Why isn't `ProcessBuilder` able to simply get these across to the other process? Also, I suspect that this all just happens on Windows (see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/26496861?noredirect=1))

Comment: "further down the road" is the operating system itself. ProcessBuilder is creating a new process just as if you did it manually in a command prompt window. It's just passing the arguments that you have given to the operating system.

Comment: The answer you give only applies to Windows. In Linux, if you pass an argument of `\"`, what is passed is exactly that, `\"`, because the arguments are passed to the operating system as a list of char arrays, which are then passed to the process as a list of char arrays, no processing is done. It's on Windows that things are different, and it's a fault of the JDK that it doesn't abstract this difference so the behaviour is the same in either case.

Comment: @JamesRoper Ok, thanks for the info. Might end up having to write a bunch of boilerplate code to create a cross-platform solution then.